# Proxem's Antelope: interface not found "ISentenceSplitter"

Tags: c#, reference, nlp, .net-assembly

I need to do some Natural Language Processing on various text inputs from user in a C# based desktop application. I am using Antelope for this purpose. The first step is to split the text into sentences. Following the documentation provided by Antelope, I used:

```
using Proxem.Antelope;
using Proxem.Antelope.Lexicon;
using Proxem.Antelope.Tools;
using Proxem.Antelope.LinkGrammar;
using Proxem.Antelope.Stanford;
using NUnit.Framework;
...
...
...
ISentenceSplitter splitter = new Tools.MIL_HtmlSentenceSplitter();
splitter.Text = text;
foreach (string sentence in splitter.Sentences)
{
    // Process sentence…
}
```

Also, I have added references to these libraries as well. But it gives the error

```
The type or namespace name 'ISentenceSplitter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\...
```

and

```
The type or namespace name 'Tools' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\...
```

I can't seem to figure out the solution. After a search on net I found out that other people are also having this problem but no one could actually found a solution. Can you please help me guys?

Comment: Just for my own curiosity's sake, I downloaded and tried to use the library.  Seems very powerful, but very very poorly documented (only that one pdf for thousands of library functions).  I poked around but could not for the life of me find the right interface or any sign of that MIL function.  I'd say if you're not too invested in this thing to try another library!

Comment: @jonsca You are very right indeed. I have finally decided to give up now with this library. Earlier on I was wondering why this library is not so popular yet so much powerful as well as free. Now I understand this is due to its poor doc. I am now thinking to use SharpNLP instead. http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/

Comment: SharpNLP is not active anymore.
The solution to use OpenNLP in .Net projects is here : https://cwiki.apache.org/OPENNLP/a-quick-guide-to-using-opennlp-from-net.html

Comment: @Bali That link is not active anymore, either :)

Comment: try OpenNLP.NET - https://github.com/sergey-tihon/OpenNLP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is to avoid using this library. No offense to the authors, they might have done v.good and hard work but if it can not be utilized after all kinds of possible tries then it is useless. They mention in doc that a function belongs to a particular interface but when you go there, it doesn't exist in ANY of the available interfaces.

For those who are curious: I did contact the authors through their site but didn't get a reply even after 8 days.

There are other alternatives available like OpenNLP (java) or its C# counterpart [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/).

Comment: since SharpNLP seems to be abandoned, try OpenNLP.NET - https://github.com/sergey-tihon/OpenNLP.NET

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It stems from the fact that antelope dlls are compatible with
.net framework 2.0 and your application is set to use .net 4.0. (possibly)
I changed my application to .net 2.0 and trouble disappeared. :)

In addition I have used both SharpNLP and Antelope. Antelope has some superior features like
Collapse detection and port to wordnet which I had not seen in SharpNLP.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple answer to this one: ISentenceSplitter is not in the actual release.  I have v 0.8.7 which should be the same **free** 2009 version everyone else has  To confirm this, I did a

```
grep -r ISentenceSplitter .
```

and nothing came back.  Try to grep with another interface that does exist such as `ILexicon` and you see all the dlls that contain ILexicon.

Note that we are talking about a **free** version and Proxem, like other reasonable companies, want to market their technology as a profitable enterprise. Therefore you have to be happy with what you have, look into the paid solutions, use something else or write your own library which the community would be very happy to have.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that same error.  Sali Hoo has the actual correct answer.  **This is not an answer for how to find or use  `ISentenceSplitter`**; however, it does show how Proxem's example application splits sentences as part of a larger process.

The example application that ships with the libraries can split sentences, so I figured the code allows for it.  After reading a bit of code, I found that their example uses the `Proxem.Antelope.Document` class for sentence splitting and syntactical parsing. Rather than decompiling the libraries to see how the guts of the `Document` constructor uses `ISentenceSplitter` (I'm fairly confident that it does) I just used the class and it actually ended up performing all of the functions I needed, not just sentence splitting.  I definitely recommend taking a look at how their example uses it, but here's the essence of my implementation:

```
public sealed class SyntaxService : ISyntaxService
{
    public SyntaxService(IParser parser, ILexicon lexicon)
    {
        m_parser = parser;
        m_lexicon = lexicon;

        // These are the setting I needed, YMMV.  They seem to add a lot of UI logic to this method :(
        m_processingResources = new ProcessingResources(m_lexicon, null, null, m_parser, 5, null, false, null, null, null, null, false);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Sentence> GetSentences(string s)
    {
        IDocument document = new Document(s, m_processingResources);

        return document.Select(Mappers.SentenceMapper.Map);
    }

    readonly IParser m_parser;
    readonly ILexicon m_lexicon;
    readonly IProcessingResources m_processingResources;
}
```

The `Sentence` class referenced here is a simplified syntax tree along with the original sentence value.  If you're not super interested in this type of dependency injection friendly wrapping and mapping, you can just use the guts of `GetSentences(string)`.